# How do you configure spring security to authenticate against a database using basic auth?

Tags: java, spring-security, basic-authentication

I am 13 weeks into coding with Java and am working on a RESTful web service. The back end is done and now I am working on creating a UI. One of the requirements is that a user log in using http basic. I have this configured to the point where when a user navigates to the page the popup dialogue comes up and you can enter one hard coded user i have in and it logs you in. But what I really need it to do is verify against users in a database. I have searched extensively to try and find a way to configure it to validate against a database but to no avail. Here is my spring-security.xml file with my dummy user.

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">

    <!-- <http auto-config="true"> <intercept-url pattern="/welcome*" access="ROLE_USER" 
        /> <form-login login-page="/login" default-target-url="/welcome" authentication-failure-url="/loginfailed" 
        /> <logout logout-success-url="/logout" /> </http> -->

    <http>
        <intercept-url pattern="/*" access="ROLE_USER" />
        <http-basic />
    </http>

    <authentication-manager>
        <authentication-provider>
            <user-service>
                <user name="tmain" password="123456" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
            </user-service>
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>

</beans:beans>
```

And here is the (I believe) only relevant information to the setup in my web.xml file.

```
<filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
```

Can anyone give me some direction on configuring spring security to authenticate against a database rather than the dummy user I have? I have a User entity in the database with a firstname, lastname, email, password, activeStatus, and timezone. The email is the user's username. Any and all help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your authentication provider should look like this:

```
<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider>
        <jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource" />
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```

Default implementation requires those tables:

```
create table users(
    username varchar_ignorecase(50) not null primary key,
    password varchar_ignorecase(50) not null,
    enabled boolean not null);

create table authorities (
    username varchar_ignorecase(50) not null,
    authority varchar_ignorecase(50) not null,
    constraint fk_authorities_users foreign key(username) references users(username));
    create unique index ix_auth_username on authorities (username,authority);
```

You can have different database structure and use something like this:

```
<jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource" authorities-by-username-query="select username,authority from users where username=?"/>
```

Don't forget to create `dataSource` bean...

And yes.. All of this can be found in [documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/springsecurity.html).

Comment: Thank you, I ended up going with this, using the different database structure that I had in place and creating a seperate table for roles. I have it working now.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a `jdbc-user-service` instead `user-service`. You can start by reading the [documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/ns-config.html#ns-auth-providers).

Comment: Thank you Dani, I will look in that direction and go from there. I have found a website with some information on doing this at:  http://www.theserverside.com/tip/-Spring-Security-Customizing-Your-User-and-Authorization-in